# HTTP 403 error when using lookupUsers for a list of twitter handles

Tags: r, http, twitter

I have a list of twitter handles in a csv and I am trying to extract data for all these handles.My csv contains around 200 twitter handles

```
users <- read.csv("Twitter.csv")
users1 <- lookupUsers(users[1:nrow(users),1])
```

however, I am getting the following error:

```
Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(paste("users", "lookup", sep = "/"),  : 
Forbidden (HTTP 403).
```

Anybody knows why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: what is in twitter.csv? 403 Errors can be because of a lot of problems. What is the exact URL being accessed?

Comment: twitteR or rTweet?

Comment: @Gerhard twitter.csv has only one column with all the twitter handles and twitteR